# CSS Alignment Within Box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a button and some text at the bottom of a div much like the example below with the Price and the Check it out button. What's the best way to do this. I've made a div, styled it to get the text, and picture right. I just need to attach the button to the right-hand side and the price to the left, inline with each other.

Similar to the product displays in the website thisiswhyimbroke.com

http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com/

^^ Price and the Check It Out button. How do I achieve this?

Comment: show your code which you tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5vYnv/ Hey made a jfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5vYnv/2/)**

Try to use reset you CSS first.

**CSS:**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#priceAndButton {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
}
#priceAndButton h4 {
    float:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#priceAndButton img {
    float:right;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button{
   float:right 
}
#price{
   float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have created a working fiddle with your requirements:**

http://jsfiddle.net/8993H/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="img-div"><img src="http://tiwibzone.tiwib.netdna-cdn.com/images/beer-chug-flowmeter1-300x250.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="rhs">
        <div class="button-nav">
            <span class="price">$35.00</span>
            <span class="check-btn"><button>Check It Out</button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main-container{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.img-div{
    width:50%

}

.img-div img{
    width:100%;
}

.rhs{
    width:48%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}

.button-nav{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    width:100%;
}

.price{
    float:left;
}

.check-btn{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i created one working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shWd4/) for your requirement.. You can re use this CSS. Hope This will help you.

```
HTML
    <div class="desc">
    <img height="200px" width="200px" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/2/2/6/11971154711712468971BigRedSmile_A_screwdriver_1.svg.med.png"/>
<p>Move over sliced bread, the water jet pack is officially the greatest thing ever. For only sixty eight grand you can own your very own water thrusting jetpack. It can lift you up to 30 feet high and thrust forward at 30 miles per hour – practically guaranteeing certain death.</p>
<div class="button">
<a href="#">Check it out</a>
</div>
<div class="price">$500.00</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .desc{
    text-align:jstify;
    width:50%;
}
.button a{
    background-color: #faab37;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.button a:hover{
background-color:#f9bd66;
}
```

Hope This is What your expected output

[image]